# Angular 2 New Forms - Custom Input Validation

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I've converted my forms to using the new forms 0.2.0.

Of course, my custom validators stopped working...any directions or examples on how to write custom input validators in this new library?

Comment: this http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had a very simple problem:
1) I didn't point NG_VALIDATORS to @angular/forms - was pointing to old forms
2) Less importantly, I wasn't using AbstractControl, just the old Control and while this didn't cause JS problems it caused typescript transpile errors.

```
 /**
 * Created by Franz on 5/8/2016.
 */
import {Directive,provide} from '@angular/core';
import {NG_VALIDATORS} from '@angular/forms';
import {PASSWORD_REGEX} from '../../common/util/rejex';
import {Validator, AbstractControl} from "@angular/forms";

function validatePassword(control: AbstractControl) {
  return PASSWORD_REGEX.test(control.value) ? null : {
    validatePassword: {valid: false}
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[validatePassword]',
  providers: [
    provide(NG_VALIDATORS, {
      useValue: validatePassword, // Alternative useExisting: PasswordValidator, but that creates and destroys objects every time.
      multi: true
    })
  ]
})
export class PasswordValidator implements Validator {
  constructor() {}

  validate(c: AbstractControl) {
    return PASSWORD_REGEX.test(c.value) ? null : {valid: false}
  };
}
```